# Transforming attribute values into xml element

Tags: xslt

Using xslt 1.0, I need to transform below input xml to output xml

--input xml

```
<Row>
    <Column name="NUMBER" sqltype="int">123</Column>
    <Column name="DEPT1" sqltype="int">A</Column>
    <Column name="CUST_EMPTYPE" sqltype="int">1</Column>
    <Column name="CUST_TIJD" sqltype="int">31</Column>
</Row>
```

--output xml

```
<EMPLOYEE xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Employee">
    <NUMBER>123</NUMBER>
    <DEPT1>IHC</DEPT1>
    <CUST_EMPTYPE>1</LASTNAME>
    <CUST_TIJD>31</FIRSTNAME>
</EMPLOYEE>
```

the Column names from input xml are not known at design time, the Column can grow..

Can anyone let me know how to achieve this?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is quite simple. One minor difference is the deviation between your `DEPT1` source and destination value (I really don't know where 'IHC' may have been coming from). I harmonized it in the following XSLT code which just sets the `Column/@name` nodes to new `EMPLOYEE` elements with the content of the old `text()` content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="/Row">
    <EMPLOYEE xmlns="http:xmlns.oracle.com/Employee">
      <xsl:for-each select="Column">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </EMPLOYEE>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of this is:

```
<EMPLOYEE xmlns="http:xmlns.oracle.com/Employee">
    <NUMBER>123</NUMBER>
    <DEPT1>A</DEPT1>
    <CUST_EMPTYPE>1</CUST_EMPTYPE>
    <CUST_TIJD>31</CUST_TIJD>
</EMPLOYEE>
```